# Create a copyable protocol default initializer

Tags: swift, protocols, type-alias, associated-types

I got this functions:

```
public protocol ContentType {
    associatedtype T

    static var allTypes: [T] { get }
    static func getContentType(contentTypeId: String) -> T

    var contentTypeId: String? { get }
}

public protocol Copyable: class {
    associatedtype T

    static func copy(old: T, new: T)
}

public protocol CopyableContentType: class {
    associatedtype T
    init(existingContentType: T, newContentTypeId: String?)
}
```

I want to provide a default initializer for a class that:

- Conforms to `ContentType`
- Conforms to `Copyable`

With above code, I always do the same in the required init: calling the copy function of the implementing class. Is there any way to omit this duplicate code across classes while keeping this initializer? I thought of it adding to a protocol extension:

```
public extension CopyableContentType where Self: ContentType & Copyable {
    typealias T = Self // So wrong but I have no idea what to put here
                       // T should be the same T as the T usud in ContentType and Copyable
    init(existingContentType: T, newContentTypeId: String?) {
        Self.copy(old: existingContentType, new: self)
    }
}
```

But this results in a few errors. I do not know what to put in at the typealias and I can not use associatedtypes. Is there any way I can provide a default initializer that calls the copy function?

Comment: A CopyableContentType should probably be Copyable and a ContentType, so maybe derive CopyableContentType from them. Its however difficult to understand what you want the API to be used like. Can you write an example which exactly shows how you would use the new API?

`extension CopyableContentType where Self: ContentType & Copyable` means only that if Self implements the two protocols, then I provide you with my 'cool' extension function which you can use then. Else you would have to implement the function yourself.

And the where does not say all associatedTypes must be the same type.

Comment: You could maybe constrain CopyableContentType's T to ContentType.T and Copyable.T with the where-clause in the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to provide a default initializer for a class that:
>
> - Conforms to `ContentType`
> - Conforms to `Copyable`

I'll attempt to answer this question assuming what you mean is that:

- You want to provide a *default implementation* of a `init(existingContentType: T, newContentTypeId: String?)` initializer, as blueprinted in `ContentType`, *if* the type conforming to `ContentType` also conforms to `Copyable`.

Let's first have a look at your `Copyable` protocol. It might be due to omission of details/use case in your question, but I don't see the need of the associated type `T` here, as the protocol basically blueprints/promises *"the `class` type conforming to `Copyable`, say e.g. `TheClassType`, will provide an implementation of the `static` `copy(from: TheClassType, to: TheClassType)` function"* — where the conforming type (`TheClassType`) is just `Self`. I.e.:

```
protocol Copyable: class {
    static func copy(from: Self, to: Self)
}
```

The same holds for `ContentType`: is there a need for an `associatedType` here, or is the `ContentType` of a given concrete type simply the type itself; i.e. `Self`? Before continuing, lets strip away the parts not relevant to your question:

```
protocol ContentType {
    var contentTypeId: String? { get }
}
```

Now, prior for any initializer to copy (not assign - we are dealing with reference types) anything *into* `self` (e.g. value type members of `self`), `self` must have been initialized (or assigned to). So to allow providing a default implementation for a `init(existingContentType: Self, newContentTypeId: String?)` initializer of `ContentType` (in case of conformance to `Copyable`; `Self` is a `class` type)—where the implementation is intended to make use of the blueprinted `copy(from: Self, to: Self)` of `copyable`—the type conforming to `ContentType` must know of a way to initializer itself *prior* to the copying step. I.e., the `ContentType` needs to blueprint some initializer that can be used to initialize `self` in the "copying initializer" prior to invoking the `copy(from:to)` method. Let's simply blueprint `init()`:

```
protocol ContentType {
    var contentTypeId: String? { get set }
    init()
}
```

Now, as the `ContentType` blueprints a `contentTypeId` member, and the copying initializer contains a `newContentTypeId` parameter, it could be sensible to provide a default implemented initializer with `contentTypeId` as its only parameter; namely `init(contentTypeId: String?)`:

```
extension ContentType {
    init(contentTypeId: String?) {
        self.init()
        self.contentTypeId = contentTypeId
    }
}
```

With this in place, we can provide the default implemented `init(existingContentType: Self, newContentTypeId: String?)` initializer as a constrained extension to `ContentType` based on conformance of `Self` to `Copyable`:

```
extension ContentType where Self: Copyable {
    init(existingContentType: Self, newContentTypeId: String?) {
        self.init(contentTypeId: newContentTypeId)
        Self.copy(from: existingContentType, to: self)
    }
}
```

#### Example

Putting the above together:

```
protocol Copyable: class {
    static func copy(from: Self, to: Self)
}

protocol ContentType {
    var contentTypeId: String? { get set }
    init()
}

extension ContentType {
    init(contentTypeId: String?) {
        self.init()
        self.contentTypeId = contentTypeId
    }
}

extension ContentType where Self: Copyable {
    init(existingContentType: Self, newContentTypeId: String?) {
        self.init(contentTypeId: newContentTypeId)
        Self.copy(from: existingContentType, to: self)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
// Copyable content type
final class Foo: ContentType, Copyable {
    // Note that since all stored properties have initial values,
    // the compiler provides a synthesized initializer for init().
    var contentTypeId: String?
    var data = 0

    static func copy(from: Foo, to: Foo) {
        to.data = from.data
    }
}

let foo1 = Foo(contentTypeId: "foo1")
foo1.data = 42
let foo2 = Foo(existingContentType: foo1, newContentTypeId: "foo2")

print(foo1.contentTypeId ?? "None", foo1.data) // foo1 42
print(foo2.contentTypeId ?? "None", foo2.data) // foo2 42


// Non-copyable content type
final class Bar: ContentType {
    var contentTypeId: String?
} // Bar has no access to
  // init(existingContentType: Self, newContentTypeId: String?)
```